# Getting error in MVC Model regarding use of List(T)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-applications

I am learning to build the application using one of the online tutorials regarding MVC. It requires to create a user db.

I am getting the following error while building the application. I have just copy-pasted the code from the tutorial. I googled few things, but I am not getting it. Please help to resolve and explain.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.EnterpriseServices;

namespace AdvancedMVCApplication.Models
{

    public class Users
    {
        public List UserList = new List();

        //action to get user details 
        public UserModels GetUser(int id)
        {
            UserModels usrMdl = null;

            foreach (UserModels um in UserList)

                if (um.Id == id)
                    usrMdl = um;
            return usrMdl;
        }

        //action to create new user 
        public void CreateUser(UserModels userModel)
        {
            UserList.Add(userModel);
        }

        //action to udpate existing user 
        public void UpdateUser(UserModels userModel)
        {

            foreach (UserModels usrlst in UserList)
            {

                if (usrlst.Id == userModel.Id)
                {
                    usrlst.Address = userModel.Address;
                    usrlst.DOB = userModel.DOB;
                    usrlst.Email = userModel.Email;
                    usrlst.FirstName = userModel.FirstName;
                    usrlst.LastName = userModel.LastName;
                    usrlst.Salary = userModel.Salary;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //action to delete exising user 
        public void DeleteUser(UserModels userModel)
        {

            foreach (UserModels usrlst in UserList)
            {

                if (usrlst.Id == userModel.Id)
                {
                    UserList.Remove(usrlst);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:** CS0305: Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments\Models\Users.cs Line:11

You can view the example here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_advanced_example.htm

Comment: `List` is a class template, you need to specify the element type, like `public List<UserModels> UserList = new List<UserModels>()`. It seems tat the code in the tutorial is wrong.

Comment: Generally, stay away from tutorialspoint, most of the stuff there is terrible and/or terribly outdated. The screenshots in that link seem to be over 5 years old. You can find better tutorials in Microsoft's own `Microsoft Docs`

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say "maybe the code blocks on tutorialspoint hide the necessary `<xxx>` after the List because it gets interpreted as an HTML tag".. but then I saw the next code block had actual html tags in just fine

To expand on the point Klaus made, it is possible to write classes in C# that are completed by the compiler rather than you. You specify some placeholder for the type of object the class deals with and then the compiler can use it to create an actual class in the background for you

```
class TenThings<T>{

  private T[] _things = new T[10];

  private T GetFirst(){
    return _things[0];
  }
}
```

T isn't any type in your program, or in the framework, for the purposes of this class/as written here but if you then say somewhere else:

```
var tt = new TenThings<string>();
```

Then the compiler can know "anywhere T is mentioned, in this case it needs to be a string" so it can knock together a class for you that is an array of ten strings and has a GetFirst method that returns a string. On the very next line you can have a `TenThings<int>` and you'll get another different type of class out that deals with ints. You created a template for the compiler to use to write code for you, and the benefit you get is that your GetFirst really does return a string in one case and an int in another. You could have just made a class like this:

```
class TenThings{

  private object[] _things = new object[10];

  private object GetFirst(){
    return _things[0];
  }
}
```

But then you have to cast everything that comes out - old classes like ArrayList worked this way, and it wasn't a great experience

List is a generic class like this new "templates" way; you really need to have another type of class in angle brackets after its name, such as `List<UserModel>` and it becomes a part of the type at the same time as dictating to the compiler how to create the template. Per the comment it seems that tutorials point forgot to put the relevant `<UserModels>` after the List

There are a few other things I take exception to in that tutorial, but talking specifically about this property; creating the List as a public field for one, calling the class UserModels when it seems to represent a single item (unwarranted plural / collections of items are typically recommended to have a name that ends with "Collection" - plurals are used for properties that are collections), I.e. it should be `public List<UserModel> UserModels { get; set; } = new List<UserModel>();`. I'll leave picking on it for not being a read only collection typed as something generic like `IEnumerable<T>` for another time :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't understand the whole thing as I am a novice in asp.net. But this surely helped.